# Keras multi gpu model with minimal GPU usage during training

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gpu, nvidia

I am trying to train a model using a TimeDistributed VGG16 as input to a RNN, but the GPUs allocate all the memory but the usage remains at the minimal value. Sometimes the usage raises but goes back to 0% (updated every 0.1s using watch). What should I do to guarantee the maximum usage of the GPUs?

nvidia-smi output

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 418.87.01    Driver Version: 418.87.01    CUDA Version: 10.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla V100-SXM2...  On   | 00000000:00:17.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   53C    P0    62W / 300W |  15882MiB / 16130MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  Tesla V100-SXM2...  On   | 00000000:00:18.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   46C    P0    61W / 300W |  15882MiB / 16130MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   2  Tesla V100-SXM2...  On   | 00000000:00:19.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   47C    P0    63W / 300W |  15882MiB / 16130MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   3  Tesla V100-SXM2...  On   | 00000000:00:1A.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   53C    P0    63W / 300W |  15882MiB / 16130MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   4  Tesla V100-SXM2...  On   | 00000000:00:1B.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   56C    P0    67W / 300W |  15882MiB / 16130MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   5  Tesla V100-SXM2...  On   | 00000000:00:1C.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   50C    P0    63W / 300W |  15882MiB / 16130MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   6  Tesla V100-SXM2...  On   | 00000000:00:1D.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   47C    P0    63W / 300W |  15882MiB / 16130MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   7  Tesla V100-SXM2...  On   | 00000000:00:1E.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   52C    P0    67W / 300W |  15882MiB / 16130MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0     30696      C   python                                     15871MiB |
|    1     30696      C   python                                     15871MiB |
|    2     30696      C   python                                     15871MiB |
|    3     30696      C   python                                     15871MiB |
|    4     30696      C   python                                     15871MiB |
|    5     30696      C   python                                     15871MiB |
|    6     30696      C   python                                     15871MiB |
|    7     30696      C   python                                     15871MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

EDIT:
Model code

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding="same",  activation="relu"), input_shape=(3, 224, 224, 3), name="Conv2D_1"))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding="same", activation="relu"), name="Conv2D_2"))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)), name="MaxPool2D_1"))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding="same", activation="relu"), name="Conv2D_3"))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding="same", activation="relu"), name="Conv2D_4"))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)), name="MaxPool2D_2"))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding="same", activation="relu"), name="Conv2D_5"))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding="same", activation="relu"), name="Conv2D_6"))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding="same", activation="relu"), name="Conv2D_7"))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)), name="MaxPool2D_3"))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding="same", activation="relu"), name="Conv2D_8"))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding="same", activation="relu"), name="Conv2D_9"))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding="same", activation="relu"), name="Conv2D_10"))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)), name="MaxPool2D_4"))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding="same", activation="relu"), name="Conv2D_11"))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding="same", activation="relu"), name="Conv2D_12"))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding="same", activation="relu"), name="Conv2D_13"))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)), name="MaxPool2D_5"))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten(name="Flatten")))
model.add(GRU(6, name="Flatten"))
model.add(Dense(1, activation="sigmoid", name="Dense"))

model = multi_gpu_model(model, gpus=8, cpu_relocation=True)
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer=opt, metrics="accuracy"])
```

EDIT:
Keras 2.3.1
Tensorflow 1.14.0

Comment: Memory is allocated completely by default in Tensorflow, it doesn't necessarily mean your network needs the whole GPU. As per the usage, check your input data pipeline. Your GPUs are fast and powerful, but if your data feeding is slow they'll have to wait.

Comment: what do you mean by "check your input data pipeline"?

Comment: You *are* feeding data to the network, right? That's an input pipeline

Comment: Yes I am but I am using keras and the code doesn't expose any of the input pipeline, I just declare the model as a [multi_gpu_model](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/multi_gpu_model), compile and execute it.

Comment: Add a sample of your setup to the question

Comment: added the code to build the model

Comment: What version of TF are you using?

Comment: Keras 2.3.1
Tensorflow 1.14.0

Comment: A few points: Check if one of your cpu cores is fully loaded. Python doesn't do multithreading so it's an indication your data preprocessing is too slow. Check your HDD/SSD usage. Is it maxed out? Are you pulling the data from the internet? Also I read that pushing data from RAM to VRAM and vice versa is comparatively slow. Tensorboard lets You see the device an operator is initialized on.